# Drupal 8 : How to render a template with variables when creating a block within a custom module?

Tags: templates, drupal, module, block

I'm trying to render a template within a block in my own custom module. The template is rendered properly but without the variables.

*ranking.module*

```
<?php

function ranking_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {

    return array(
        'block__ranking' => array(
            'template' => 'block--ranking',
            'variables' => array('title' => 'test'),
        ),

    );
}
```

*RankingBlock.php*

```
<?php
/**
 * @file
 * Contains \Drupal\ranking\Plugin\Block\RankingBlock.
 */

namespace Drupal\ranking\Plugin\Block;
use Drupal\Core\Block\BlockBase;

/**
 * Provides a 'Ranking' Block
 *
 * @Block(
 *   id = "ranking_block",
 *   admin_label = @Translation("Ranking Block"),
 * )
 */
class RankingBlock extends BlockBase {
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function build() {
        return array(
            '#title' => 'This is an awesome title'
        );
    }

}
```

Of course, I try to display the variables with {{ title }} (in templates/block--ranking.html.twig)

I followed mainly (but not only) [this tutorial](http://blog.thesecretlab.nl/how-to-create-a-customized-template-for-your-custom-block-in-drupal-8/.)

Could you please tell me what's wrong with my code ?

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved the problem. The following line was missing :
'#theme' => 'ranking' in RankingBlock.php

```
<?php
/**
 * @file
 * Contains \Drupal\ranking\Plugin\Block\RankingBlock.
 */

namespace Drupal\ranking\Plugin\Block;
use Drupal\Core\Block\BlockBase;

/**
 * Provides a 'Ranking' Block
 *
 * @Block(
 *   id = "ranking_block",
 *   admin_label = @Translation("Ranking Block"),
 * )
 */
class RankingBlock extends BlockBase {
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function build() {
        return array(
            '#theme' => 'ranking',
            '#title' => 'This is an awesome title'
        );
    }

}
```